# Changing image by clicking in image from class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 images in the same class. Wen I click one of the images of that class i want to replace that image, but only that image and no other from the same class:

```
<img src="1..." class="things">
<img src="2..." class="things">
<img src="3..." class="things">
<img src="4..." class="things">
```

In the javascript code (using jQuery) I have:

```
$(".things").click(function(){
$(this).attr('src', 'other_image.png');
})
```

It doesn't do nothing!
Before I have a .hover() for change the icon image when the mouse is hover it! Maybe is that the problem!

Comment: `;` is still missing at end of click handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few mistakes in code - change it to --

```
$(".things").click(function(){
   $(this).attr('src', 'other_image.png');
});
```

---

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YWjSG/)

---

[New Demo with Hover](http://jsfiddle.net/uyVv8/1/)

```
    var isClicked = false;
    $(".changeImage").hover(function(){  
       isClicked = false;
       $(this).attr("src","http://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/210376/124505092/stock-photo-beautiful-businesswoman-portrait-124505092.jpg");
     },function(){
   if(!isClicked)  
       $(this).attr("src","http://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/91282/117241141/stock-photo-image-of-pretty-businesswoman-looking-at-camera-117241141.jpg");
   else
        isClicked = false;
}).click(function(){
     isClicked = true;
});
```

Comment: Sorry... I write it wrong here! Im my code I have the $(".things")!

Comment: Ok! I think i detect the error!...
Is because de .hover event. Because in the callback of it i change the image again!!
Is not any other way to disable the hover event after I click in the image?

Comment: ive updated answer and gave demo also. Can you post the code for `hover` handler also ?

Comment: `$('.things').hover(function() {
                $(this).attr('src', './img/select_image.png');
                
              }, function() {
                $(this).attr('src', './img/unselect_image.png');
                
                });´

Comment: Ok .. check out latest fiddle mentioned in answer.

Comment: Ok! I change the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/YWjSG/1/
Can I remove the .hover handler from the image? I think is that who is causing the problem. 
I try to change the class, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Great! I think that it gonna works! Very simple!! How can't i see that! Many thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to do ? What I understand is, you want to change image on hover and keep it to changed image to as it is when user clicks on image. Is that so ? Then fiddle i've mentioned does exactly same. here's another fiddle with little change http://jsfiddle.net/uyVv8/2/

Answer (score 2):

You missed some quotes I think:

```
$(".things").click(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'other_image.png');
})
```

Comment: Sorry... I write it wrong here! Im my code I have the $(".things")!

Answer (score 0):

hey buddy please check out this code..

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function (){
$("img").click(function(){
$(this).attr('src', 'Blue hills.jpg');
});
});
```

it works fine for me.